# How to update data with a trigger function and a join

Tags: postgresql, join, trigger, functions

I have two relations :

```
CREATE TABLE relation_a (id_a int PRIMARY KEY, field_1 int);
CREATE TABLE relation_b (id_b int PRIMARY KEY,fk_a int REFERENCES relation_a(id_a), field_1 int);
INSERT INTO relation_a VALUES (1,100), (2,101), (3,102);
INSERT INTO relation_b VALUES (1,1), (2,2), (3,3)
```

I want to create a trigger which always set :

```
SET b.field_1 = a.field_1 FROM relation_a a, relation_b b WHERE b.fk_a = a.id_a
```

I tried something like this :

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION function1() RETURNS trigger AS 
$$
BEGIN
    UPDATE relation_b as b
    SET field_1 = a.field_1
    FROM relation_a a
    WHERE a.id_a = new.fk_a;
END
$$
LANGUAGE PLPGSQL;

CREATE TRIGGER trigger1
   AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE 
   ON relation_b
   FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE function1();
```

If i try to insert or update data in relation_b, i got a very long error message i can't understand :[image: error message]

Can someone explain me the right way ? Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem was that after each update on relation_b, the trigger asks to update relation_b, so it calls itself and enter in a loop.

I solved it configuring the trigger to begin when one field is updated, except the field it updates :

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION function1() RETURNS trigger AS 
$$
BEGIN
    UPDATE relation_b as b
    SET field_1 = a.field_1
    FROM relation_a a
    WHERE a.id_a = new.fk_a and b.id_b = new.id_b;

    RETURN new;
END
$$
LANGUAGE PLPGSQL;

DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS trigger1 on relation_b;
CREATE TRIGGER trigger1
   AFTER UPDATE OF id_b, fk_a
   ON relation_b
   FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE function1();

DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS trigger2 on relation_b;
CREATE TRIGGER trigger2
   AFTER INSERT
   ON relation_b
   FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE function1();
```

Comment: You don't need an UPDATE statement in the trigger if you make it a BEFORE trigger - which will be much more efficient. https://pastebin.com/8QJd3RSv

Comment: Indeed, it works, and it's more efficient. Do you want to post it as an anwer to let me accept it ?

Answer (score 0):

Just `SET` the value for `field_1` `BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE`.  Just, make sure you use the alias for the `new` row of data.

*needs to be edited for postgresql syntax*

```sql
CREATE TRIGGER trigger1
   BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE 
   ON relation_b
   FOR EACH ROW
begin
  -- "new" represent "current row being inserted/updated"
  -- just modify the values BEFORE it is stored in the DB

  select a.field_1
    into new.field_1
  from relation_a a
  where a.id_a = new.fk_a;

  -- add exception handle where "no data is found"
end;
```

Comment: it doesn't work the way you wrote it, and i don't know what to edit. Anyway, i found a solution, thank you very much for your help